# R removing na in rows of a selected column by id

Tags: r

I have a data.frame:

```
A <- c(1:10,"NA")
df <- as.data.frame(A)
df$B <-c(11:21)
df$C <-c(21:31)
df
```

I can interrogate columns selected by id:

```
id <-"A"
df[df[,id]==5,]
```

However I am having problems removing rows with na in a selected column:

```
df[!is.na(df[,id]),]
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: By putting `NA` in quotes, it is now not an `NA`, but a character (actually, a `factor` with the way you created your `data.frame`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NA` that you have included when creating the variable A is a character.  Try your example with

```
A <- c(1:10, NA)
```

instead.  Or, if you intend for the `NA` to be a character, you could try

```
df[df[,id]!="NA", ]
```